# Считывание картинок из одной папки в другую java

Tags: java

Не могу понять как из одной папки считать все картинки и перенести их в другую папку. Одну картинку я могу, а вот несколько не знаю как. Напрашивается цикл, но как это все реализовать.

Comment: добавляйте код, который вы написали. тот, который одну картинку успешно переносит, а мы подскажем, как туда добавить цикл

Comment: Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос, добавьте в него ваш код и более развёрнутое объяснение проблемы. На данный момент не понятно, что у вас не получается.

Comment: с чем конкретно у вас возникли сложности?